# Pass two parameters to WEB API call using angular post

Tags: c#, json, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have the following post method in my WEB API controller:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendPost(Application application)
```

I call it through javascript using *angular.js* `$http.post` and pass through the application parameter as JSON:

```
$http.post("/api/AController/SendPost", JSON.stringify(application)).
            success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
}
```

This works.

Now I want to pass through a second parameter as a simple string (I can't modify the existing application JSON object).I tried a few different ways suggested on the web but none of them seem to work. I need to be able to do soemthing like this:

**Controller:**

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendPost(RentalApplication application,string test)
```

**Javascript:**

```
           $http.post("/api/TessIntegration/SendPost", {application:JSON.stringify(application),test:"Some value"}).
            success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution using *Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject*:

**Controller:**

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendPost(JObject data)
{
    RentalApplication application = data["application"].ToObject<RentalApplication>();
    string test = data["test"].ToObject<string>();
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
        var data = {
            application : application,
            test : "sample value"
        };

        $http.post("/api/TessIntegration/SendPost",data).
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
```

}

Answer (score 5):

You cannot get multiple objects from the body in WebAPI.

If you were passing two complex objects, the solution would be to wrap them into another complex object.

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendPost(SuperComplex request)

public class SuperComplex {
    public Application Application { get; set; }
    public AnotherObject Object { get; set; }
}

$http.post("/api/AController/SendPost", { application: application, Object: {} });
```

Now if the 2nd parameters is a simple object (such as a string) you can just pass it by queryString instead.

```
$http.post("/api/AController/SendPost?test=some+value", application );
```

Also, you don't have to stringify, Angular does it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Update to @Denys answer. Use of JObject is not necessary. Simply use `JSON.stringify(data)` in your javascript as:

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
var data = {
        application : application,
        test : "sample value"
    };

    $http.post("/api/TessIntegration/SendPost",data).
    success(function (JSON.stringify(data), status, headers, config) {
```

**C#**

Change definition of controller endpoint as:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendPost(RentalApplication application, string test)
{
    RentalApplication application = data["application"].ToObject<RentalApplication>();
    string test = data["test"].ToObject<string>();
}
```