# How to pass two objects to web api?

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Here is my WebAPI POST method which expects `BookingDetail` and `BookingVenue` objects:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateUserSession]
    public JsonResult CheckBooking(BookingDetail BookingDetail, BookingVenue objBV)
    {
        try
        {
            if (BookingDetail != null && objBV != null)
            {
                bool result = Ibook.checkBookingAvailability(BookingDetail, objBV);
                if (result == false)
                {
                    return Json("NotAvailable");
                }
                else
                {
                    return Json("Available");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return Json("Available");
            }
        }
```

}

Angular code from where I'm getting the values from UI and making a post passing these 2 objects:

```
this.checkbookingavailability = function (Book) {
    var BookingVenueObj = {
        EventTypeID: Book.EventSelected,
        VenueID: Book.Venueselected,
        GuestCount: Book.NoofGuest,            
    };
    var BookingDetailObj = {
        BookingDate: Book.BookingDate
    };
    var response =
       $http({
           method: "POST",
           url: "/Booking/CheckBooking/",
           headers: {
               'RequestVerificationToken': $cookies.get('EventChannel')
           },
           data: { BookingDetail: BookingDetailObj, BookingVenue: BookingVenueObj }

       });
    return response;

}
```

Problem is in my WebAPI code, both the objects as null

Comment: You can not pass two object to web api. You can do like this `public JsonResult CheckBooking([frombody]dynamic value)`

Comment: @Div: we can pass two objects in a web api.

Comment: @ismail baig [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14407458/webapi-multiple-put-post-parameters)

Comment: @Div: the link seems to be the question for passing some data from url and other from body which is obvious is not the correct way. but here the question is to pass the object from body (typical POST)

Comment: You can also use JObject for this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32731486/pass-two-parameters-to-web-api-call-using-angular-post

Answer (score 2):

You can only pass *one object in the body* so I would recommend you to create a *new DTO* "BookingDto" for that containing `BookingDetail` and `BookingVenue` as member and change the signature of your WebAPI to this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateUserSession]
public JsonResult CheckBooking([FromBody]BookingDto bookingObj)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `serialize` JSON object which you are sending to server just by calling `JSON.stringify` over object.

```
var response =
   $http({
       method: "POST",
       url: "/Booking/CheckBooking/",
       headers: {
           'RequestVerificationToken': $cookies.get('EventChannel')
       },
       data: JSON.stringify({ 
         BookingDetail: BookingDetailObj, 
         BookingVenue: BookingVenueObj
       })
   });
return response;
```

Answer (score 0):

As dear Pankaj mentioned you need to `Serialize` your data objects with `Stringify` function in javascript, Also consider that you must mention that this http request contain `Application/JSON` content. All these can be shown here:

```
var response =
   $http({
       method: "POST",
       url: "/Booking/CheckBooking/",
       headers: {
           'RequestVerificationToken': $cookies.get('EventChannel'),
           'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
       },
       data: JSON.stringify({ 
         BookingDetail: BookingDetailObj, 
         BookingVenue: BookingVenueObj
       })
   });
return response;
```